# Using the file descriptor returned from C extension to read the files in python

Tags: c, windows, python-2.7, cross-platform

When I try reading a file in python, it blocks other processes from editing that file. Even though the file is opened in read mode.

I couldn't find and option which would enable me to achieve this. So, what am trying to do is, send the file name to a C extension and open the file there with required option and return the file descriptor from there.
And, use this descriptor to get the file object and read the file.

The code I have tried is:

The C code fileread.h

```
#include <python.h>

static PyObject* fileread(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    char* filename = NULL;
    int fd = 0;
    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &filename)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    fd = _sopen(filename, 0x0000, 0x40, 0x0100);
    // _sopen(filename,_O_RDONLY, _SH_DENYNO, _S_IREAD);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", fd);
}

static PyMethodDef fileread_funcs[] = {
    { "fileread", (PyCFunction)fileread,
    METH_VARARGS, "read file in blocks" },
    { NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
};

void initfileread(void)
{
    Py_InitModule3("fileread", fileread_funcs,
        "Extension for file read!");
}
```

And, the fileread.py is:

```
import os
import fileread

def ReadDataBlockByBlock(dirPath, fileName):
    path = os.path.join(dirPath, fileName)

    if os.access(path, os.R_OK):
        fd = PyObjectAsFileDescriptor(fileread.fileread(path))
        fp = os.fdopen(fd,'r') #Is Error: Expects integer

    for block in read_in_chunks(fp):
        print block
        print '*' * 80

    os.close(fd)

 def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1096):
    """Function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""

    while True:
        data = os.read(file_object, chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
```

When I try to do fdopen() here, it throws an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Before you claim Python is blocking other processes from accessing the file, try opening it for read simultaneously from two different Python processes.  This works well for me on Linux...

Comment: Am sorry, I should have mentioned its on windows. And, I tried reading a file from python script. When I try to edit n save the file at the same time, it doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: But is that your editor, or Python?  To rule out Python, open two different cmd windows, fire up Python in both of them, and open the file for reading in each one.  If that works, then it's your editor complaining that it won't open a file that another process has open.

Comment: Sure. Will try that. Thanks

Comment: You were right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Python does not lock files, but see the `fcntl` module if you need to do so.

But other processes which do lock files may not be able to acquire the lock if a Python process has a file open.  (This is heavily OS-dependent behavior.)

To prove that it is not Python that is keeping the other process from accessing the file, open two different terminal programs or cmd windows, fire up Python in both of them, and open the file for reading in each one.  This should work, and will show that it's the other process complaining that it cannot open (and lock) a file that your Python process has open, and not Python itself acquiring a lock on the file.

In general, the best way to deal with this is to open the file, do your file operations, and close it again right away.  Unfortunately, though, if your editor does not let other processes open files, that is a problem that you are going to have to deal with.  You should check your editor configuration settings, to see if it has one for exclusive access that you can turn off, and if not, you should consider a different editor.